# how to encode an Int in swift using the protocol Encoder

Tags: ios, swift

I was surfing in swift STD particularly in the "Int structure", and there is a function named

```
func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/int/2894461-encode.

I saw many examples using this function, however all the examples contained structs and classes I was wondering how can I use this function to encode a variable of type Int.

Thanks

Comment: `encoder.singleValueContainer().encode(5)`

Answer (score 0):

As you may be aware, `Int` conforms to [Encodable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/encodable) which defines the `encode(to:)` method that you have discovered. You can use an encoder such as a [JSONEncoder](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsonencoder) or [PropertyListEncoder](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/propertylistencoder) to encode any type that conforms to the `Encodable` protocol. For example:

```
let encoder = JSONEncoder()
let jsonData = try encoder.encode(5)
```

You don't need to worry about calling `encode(to:)` on `Int` directly. Your encoder should handle all of that under the hood.